# Is there asm nop equivalent in java?

Tags: java, debugging

When I program C/C++ with Visual Studio I often use `__asm nop;` command to insert a *noop* code in order to have something to break on. For instance:

```
if (someCondition())
{
  __asm nop;
}
```

I have no idea what to do when the condition occurs, but I want to stop the execution and examine the current state. Sometimes `someCondition()` is simple enough to create a conditional breakpoint, but conditional breakpoints slow down the execution significantly, besides it is not always possible.

Now, in C# I break into the debugger directly either by calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` or `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`.

Now I am forced to program Java and until now I have found no better alternative than just do `System.out.println("bla-bla")` and set a breakpoint there. Again, please consider the case when a conditional breakpoint is not feasible.

So, I wonder - is there an `__asm nop` or `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` alternative in Java?

Comment: I use System.out.println() in this case. Why don't you want to use this?

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but in C/C++ you can use the DEBUG_BREAK(); macro which will break into the debugger automatically without you having to add a manual breakpoint.

Comment: @Neil - if I am not mistaken, `DEBUG_BREAK()` is just `__asm int 3` - another one of my favorites.

Comment: @mark you are correct in the case of x86, but for other architectures it is whatever they use.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In bytecode you have a `nop` instruction, but there's no `nop` statement in the Java language.

You can add an extra `;` on a line by itself and the code will still compile, but that's not much more meaningful than adding an empty line.

Another "does nothing" statement could be:

```
assert true;
```

which has no side-effects what so ever, and can be turned off when executing the program.

As it turns out, `assert true` does not seem to generate any bytecode instructions, which causes break-points on assert true to be skipped all together. Eclipse is however able to break on a statement such as

```
assert Boolean.TRUE;
```

which is quite similar.

Comment: Another good technique is to make a dummy method, use it everywhere, and put the breakpoint in the method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26172741/895245

Comment: As of 2018, neither _Eclipse_ (4.7) nor _IDEA_ (2017.3) can break on `;`.

Comment: Actually, even `jdb` doesn't support this, e. g.: `VM Started: Unable to set deferred breakpoint com.example.Class1:11 : No code at line 11 in com.example.Class1`.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-06 doesn't break on `assert Boolean.TRUE;`.

Answer (score 10):

Java interprets this as an empty statement:

```java
;
```

Though, as noted in comments, Eclipse won't let you set a breakpoint here. If you want something useless that you can put a breakpoint on that's also nice and easy to type, I suggest:

```java
if(false){}
```

Your compiler might warn you that this is never entered, which can be useful for reminding you to take it out before compiling for production. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

You can just put in any arbitrary assignment statement that doesn't do anything, e.g.

```
if (someCondition()) {
  int t=0;
}
```

The debugger will be happy to break on this. Since `t` is local to the block, it can't possibly have any side effects (and will get JIT-compiled out of existence in production code).

Alternatively, you can write a static function which has a breakpoint permanently set inside it, so you can just do:

```
if (someCondition()) {
  breakPoint();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to set a breakpoint on a `;` in Eclipse.

Comment: Neither you can in other IDEs, for example in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: In Eclipse Mars, with "remove unneeded brackets" enabled in the formatter or save steps, the first example turns into 'if (someCondition()) int t=0;' which is invalid code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm separating this into a new answer because I'm surprised no one has said this, yet. **Modern IDEs let you add logic to breakpoints!** Instead of compiling a dedicated `if` statement just for debugging, place the breakpoint somewhere you actually care about, then right-click it and select Breakpoint Properties!

[image: The right-click menu on OS X, with Breakpoint Properties at the bottom]
[image: The Breakpoint Properties dialog, showing hit count, conditions, etc.]

Comment: By "Modern IDEs", I mean those I currently worked with: Eclipse, Xcode, NetBeans, IntelliJ, and Visual Studio. Others probably also have this feature.

Comment: Meta: Thank you, whoever voted this up, for [pushing me over the edge to being a trusted member](http://i.imgur.com/vazPIX5.png) 

Answer (score 3):

I did not find a perfect solution for this, but here is the solution I like most. Probably not efficient but it lets you place a breakpoint, Eclipse does not complain or warns and from the code reader's point of view, it is obvious what you want to do.

```
// Silly method that allows me to make noop
private static void noop() {

}

public otherMethod() { 
    // Here I need breakpoint
    noop();
}
```

If I want to precondition breakpoint I place the condition before:

```
public otherMethod() { 
    // Here I need breakpoint
    if(someCondition())
        noop();
}
```